# hs-minor-mode: hide only some comment

Tags: code-folding, hideshow

In `ESS` mode with `hs-minor-mode` on, I want to collapse only those comments which directly belong to a function, not other comments which are separated by newlines.  Take this example:

```r
##############
## Section foo
##############

#' This does foobar
#' Returns nothing.
foobar <- function(x) message("hello")
```

What I would like the comments to fold into is:

```r
##############
## Section foo
##############

#' This does foobar...
foobar <- function(x) message("hello")
```

And what I get so far is just:

```r
##############...
foobar <- function(x) message("hello")
```

Now, is there a way to fold just some "connected" comment sections and keep others unfolded?

Answer (score 0):

Check this variable out `hs-hide-comments-when-hiding-all`

> hs-hide-comments-when-hiding-all is a variable defined in
> ‘hideshow.el’. Its value is t
>
> Documentation: Hide the comments too when you do an ‘hs-hide-all’.
>
> You can customize this variable.